# why referenced c# dll is in full path in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, reference, path

why the referenced dll of a c# project is in full path? when i move the source code to a different pc, the reference is broken.

Comment: Have you checked your project file in notepad to see if the path is full there too ? Because, it is displayed as full in all my VS2010 projects, but the path is really relative in the project file.

Comment: @Pierre, i checked, some are in full path, some are not. i am trying to figure out why.

Comment: I bet it's those outside the solution folder.

Comment: @Pierre, no, maybe it's the way how i add those reference that makes the difference. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio tries not to use full paths to DLL's whenever possible to avoid situations like this.  It tries to reference DLL's with a relative path if possible.

Is there a relative path in this scenario that would work?  If so could you try editing the .csproj file manually and setting it to use this relative path and see what happens?

Comment: Although VS 2010 might show you the full path of the library (Same happens with MonoDevelop), it normally puts the relative path in the .csproj file. To verify, open your .csproj using any text editor (as suggested by JaredPar) and check the paths of your external .dlls